# JQuery selector activating in the wrong control in ASP.NET webforms

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-selectors

So in this master pages site, i have included the below in the masterpage to enable datapicker in all textboxes containing the word "Date" in their id

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<script type="text/javascript">

    function pageLoad(sender, args) {
        $(document).ready(function () {


            $("[id*='Date']").datepicker({
                showOn: 'button',
                buttonImageOnly: true,
                buttonImage: 'http://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/datepicker/images/calendar.gif'
            });
            $("[id*='Date']").click(function () {
                $("[id*='Date']").datepicker('show');
            });
        });
    }
</script>
```

This woks fine on pages with just one such textbox. But on pages with multiple datetime textboxes (txtStartDate and txtCompletionDate), if you click on the first one, the second one gets focused and subsequently receives the value selected from the calendar popup. This issue does not happen if i click on the calendar icon next to the textbox or if i select the second textbox. This issue doesnt happen either if i specifically declare the full name of the textbox ID's in the selector.

Comment: Why are you using `$(document).ready(function () {` in a function?

Comment: share your html code too

Comment: @Satpal Good question, i had initially done this to enable jquery code to work on postbacks too, but looks like i can remove the $(document).ready function and this still works fine, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `this`, it refers the element which invoked the event in the event handler.

Use

```
$("[id*='Date']").click(function () {
    $(this).datepicker('show');
});
```

instead of

```
$("[id*='Date']").click(function () {
    $("[id*='Date']").datepicker('show');
});
```

Comment: Fast and correct reply. Kinda silly how i did not think of it, but google did not help either surprisingly